# Wifi card not detected - Archlinux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, wifi

I've recently installed Archlinux on my Asus N76V Notebook but the system doesn't seem to detect my wifi card. It is not listed in any of the normal detection commands :

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 630M] (rev a1)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 08)
```

lsusb

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2883 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The interface for wifi is not installed :

ip link

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

How can I identify the wireless device and install the appropriate driver?

I use Archlinux, up-to-date, with kernel 3.14.2.

Comment: Please identify the specific OS and its release number.

Comment: Is this a built-in or an external WiFi card? Got any hints about brand, chipset,etc?

Comment: It is a built-in card, but I don't have any idea about the brand (though I think it might be Intel or Atheros). That's the trouble: I can't detect it, so I can't identify it.

Comment: Maybe try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/115293/wireless-card-unseen-by-lspci and see if you are able to see your card in `lspci` again. My guess is probably some broadcom card, since most of the google search results is riddled with this problem for their card.

Comment: I guessing you've checked it out already, but just incase take a look at the Arch Wiki page on [Broadcom Wireless](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless#Driver_selection). I had a similar problem on my Laptop, which used a Bordcom driver, and to fix it I installed the [broadcom-wl-dkms](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/broadcom-wl-dkms/) package from the `AUR` (using `makepkg -sri`), then rebooting my system.